# How to check key is incorrect for decryption of DES/CBC/NoPadding?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des, cbc-mode

I have encrypted a file using DES/CBC/NoPadding algorithm.
When decrypting the same file with the incorrect key, I am not getting any error or exception instead it just writes the data to the output file in the encrypted manner only.

Which approach should I follow that informs that wrong key is provided?

Comment: The decryption function (esp. padding mode = NONE) is not been able to detect a wrong key, it just consumes (block of) bytes and run some mathematical operations on it. Using a "wrong" key just give another (wrong) output. Choose an algorithm with a padding (e.g. PKCS5 / PKCS7) or calculate a HMAC on the (original) plaintext and compare the result with the HMAC on the decrypted data.

Comment: How HMAC can be calculated for DES 64 bit encryption algo? any reference?

Comment: The HMAC is indepent from any encryption, search for "Java HMAC" :-)